# 'mobileffmpeg/LogDelegate.h' file not found xcode while build ipa using flutter

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter, macos

[flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rEov.jpg)

1). I have applied the following commands but it did not worked for me:

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- flutter pub upgrade
- cd iOS
- pod install

2). I have used the configuration of ffmpeg package as well:

**

iOS (Flutter >= 2.x) Edit ios/Podfile, add the following block before target 'Runner do and specify the package name in  section :

**

```
# "fork" of method flutter_install_plugin_pods (in fluttertools podhelpers.rb) to get lts version of ffmpeg
def flutter_install_plugin_pods(application_path = nil, relative_symlink_dir, platform)
  # defined_in_file is set by CocoaPods and is a Pathname to the Podfile.
  application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
  raise 'Could not find application path' unless application_path

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.

  symlink_dir = File.expand_path(relative_symlink_dir, application_path)
  system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.

  symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
  system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)

  plugins_file = File.join(application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins-dependencies')
  plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file, platform)
  plugin_pods.each do |plugin_hash|
    plugin_name = plugin_hash['name']
    plugin_path = plugin_hash['path']
    if (plugin_name && plugin_path)
      symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, plugin_name)
      File.symlink(plugin_path, symlink)

      if plugin_name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
        pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/<package name>', :path => File.join(relative_symlink_dir, 'plugins', plugin_name, platform)
      else
        pod plugin_name, :path => File.join(relative_symlink_dir, 'plugins', plugin_name, platform)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

3). I do these commands as well:

- go into ios folder
- delete the Podfile.lock file
- rm -rf Pods
- pod cache clean --all
- pod deintegrate
- pod setup
- pod install
  but the result is nothing.

Please help out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this package is no longer supported and has been replaced with this one:

https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter

replace your package and dependencies and try again.